# Why is the error showing ` catch((err) => {` is not a function?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, authentication, bcrypt

I'm trying to authenticate users when registering on my app using Nodejs, express and mongoDB.
The user gets registered successfully and added to my database but then I get this error in the console that .catch is not a function. Which is after my user has been successfully registered and password hashed successfully as well.

what is the cause of the error that makes my server to crash?

console error:

### .catch((err) => {

### TypeError: res.status(...).send(...).catch is not a function

My code:

```
  bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
  .then((hashedPassword) => {
    const user = new User({
      email: req.body.email,
      password: hashedPassword,
    });
     user.save().then((result) => {
       res.status(201)
          .send({
           message: "User created successfully",
           result,
         }).catch((err) => { 

       // error is pointing at this line of code
           res.status(500).send({
             message: "Error creating User",
             err,
           });
         });
     });
  }).catch((err) => {
    res.status(500).send({
      message: "Password was not hashed successfully",
      err,
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: "*what is the cause of the error*" `res.send` neither returns a promise, nor something that has a `.catch()` method. It's unclear why you expect it to do either of that nor why would you even add a `.catch()` to `res.send()` as it's not going to fail anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You placed/copied the catch to the wrong place, it should be catching the error when creating the user not when you send.

So change:

```
user.save().then((result) => {
   res.status(201).send({
     message: "User created successfully",
     result,
   }).catch((err) => { 
     // error is pointing at this line of code
     res.status(500).send({
       message: "Error creating User",
       err,
     });
   });
});
```

to

```
user.save().then((result) => {
   res.status(201).send({
     message: "User created successfully",
     result,
   })
}).catch((err) => {
   res.status(500).send({
     message: "Error creating User",
     err,
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved my problem ... users gets registered successfully, authenticated, and can login successfully as well and my server doesn't crash.

Comment: I did that but I need more reputation for it to be visible.

Answer (score -2):

### A few aolutions

#### 1.Check your catch() function

You can try to make the code become clearer such as using a try catch function as the code maybe have some problems.

#### 2. If problem #1 didn't work

Re-install express(if the problem didn't solve)

```bash
npm install express
```

Comment: How would reinstalling express solve an error resulting from calling a non-existent function?

Comment: Because this response problem may be the problem of express(or other NPM packages),some npm packages have problems when downloading via command line.This will result in incomplete packages(I've experienced this),then re-install packages can solve the problem if everything in the project have no problems.

Comment: `res.send()` never returning a promise will not be fixed by reinstalling the package. Because in Express `res.send()` never returns a promise. The logic OP has makes no sense for that anyway - if sending the response fails, then the code should send another response? That can never work. If it failed once 1. It's most likely going to fail again. 2. It's also evidently not a problem with the user creation, as the message sent back on error indicates. Because returning the response *after the user is created* clearly is not due to an error with the user creation.

Comment: It wasn't express, it was the structure of my code and that have resolved without changing res.send or anything. Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).